# Electron app won't close when pressing close button in titlebar

Tags: windows, electron, desktop

I tried to make a chess game which is downloadable, but you can't close the application via the close button in the titlebar and I don't know why

This is the code on the index.js (the file which electron basically wrote for me and I just configurized size...):

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
    
// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
    app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 870,
        height: 870,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            devTools: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
        },
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        resizable: false,
        hasShadow: false,
        //titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

I tried many changes from the Internet, but nothing seems to work, so it would be great if someone could fix this code, or at least tell me what I have to do to make the close button in the titlebar from the app work

Comment: Are you saying when you click the close window button, nothing happens or are you saying that the window closes but the app does not quit completely? What OS are you using?

Comment: Your code above works for me. IE: When pressing the window close button, it closes your application.